# Commandline option for robot framework to get console output instead of get output logs

Tags: robotframework

How to get robot framework running output in console instead of logs by using command line option?

Comment: Robot already gives output in the console. What sort of output are you expecting that's different from what you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option.
You might be able to create something with the [listener interface](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#listener-interface), hooking up at suite/case/keyword level and getting the current output, printing to console filtered info.

Have in mind the logging is excessive - look at a sample output.xml, having that much information in the console may be overwhelming.

Comment: Thank you Todor Minakov. Is there any way to customize robot framework test case file from (.robot) to normal python script(.py) only?

Comment: What do you mean by "to customize"?

Comment: Actually i dont want to use robot syntax instead using normal python syntax only i want to write both test cases and test libraries.

Comment: If you have cases in robot framework syntax, you cannot convert them to python (with some tool); if you want to create your cases directly in python syntax - yes, that's doable. By the way, writing them in python will not make the logging appear on the console, just like that - you'll have to take similar steps as in the RF syntax.